# How to use preg_replace on multidimensional array and with a multidimensional array as source for the replacment

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, preg-replace

Hi guys i have the following arrays and i want to replace only the date from $a[1] with $b[1], $a[2] with $b[2] ...

```
$a=array(
    1 => 'BLALBLSALV23.04.2014bjwjfdwjd'
    2 => 'BLAJSDJSAD24.04.2015bjwjfdwjd'
    ...
    )
$b=array(
    1 => '20140423'
    2 => '20150424'
    ...
    )
```

Im using preg_replace but the result doesn't show any change, this is the code i use

```
$i=0;
$anlagDat = "#(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,4})#";   
foreach($a as &$value){
preg_replace($anlagDat,$b[$i],$value);
$i++;
}
```

I know that it cant be a wrong reggex because i use it prior in the programm

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of `preg_replace`.

Comment: Apart from @Jon's comment you might want to initialize your `$i` variable. If you have used it before you will get unexpected results. Or you get it directly in the loop: `foreach($a as $i => &$value)`. And unset your `$value` variable after the loop to avoid bugs later on.

Comment: @Jon thanks jon that was my mistake

Comment: @jeroen in my original code i had it initialize one line above with $i=0; i edited the post thanks for making the post better !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_replace return new string with changes. Try this snippet:

```
$anlagDat = "#(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,4})#";
foreach($a as &$value) {
    $value = preg_replace($anlagDat,$b[$i],$value);
    $i++;
}
```